# MySQL resources utilisation optimisation

Tags: mysql, select, query-optimization

There are 2 queries:

```
select * from X inner join Y on X.id=Y.id where X.text = "ABC";
```

and

```
select * from X inner join Y on X.id=Y.id and X.text = "ABC";
```

Is there any sufficient difference in memory utilisation during execution and which one is less greedy? Prove your answer please.

Comment: This query is simple and both will return the same results, but be aware that moving conditions from the where clause into a join clause in more complex queries can change the result of the query and how it functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a simple select like this the query optimizer *should* optimize both queries to the same code.

Which query is greedier depends on your indexes.

If there is an index on *Y.id* but no index on *X.text* bot queries will perform the same.

If there is no index on *Y.id* and no index on *X.text* you have to get lucky. If MySQL optimizes correctly, the first query might be faster as it applies the where before the join (which will be a nested loop join).

If there is and index on Y.id and X.text, the first query will be faster because it can utilize both indexes. It will first apply the where clause and then do an index join.

Basic rules: *Do not* apply where conditions on the leading table (X) in JOIN clauses. Do include where conditions of the joined table (Y) in the join clauses (especially when doing a left join).

Comment: You wrote "query optimizer should optimize both queries to the same code", I suspect you're right, but what to be 100% sure. Could you give me a link to the docs etc. to prove this?

Comment: I wrote should, because that is what the query optimizer normally does (not what I think it should do). Unfortunately, the query optimizer does not always decide correctly (it depends on its statistics which can lead to wrong decisions). I do not have a link to the Docs, I know this, because I run a Data Warehouse on MySQL and do a lot of query tuning, plus I talk a lot with MySQL Professionals from Oracle. A lot in MySQL is trial and error. Write your query, run EXPLAIN, optimize, run it, write it differently, compare.

Comment: I don't think the query optimizer would create the same query plan for both of these queries because they function differently.  Although they can be seen as the same thing to humans, they are written to function differently and I don't think the query optimizer would make them the same.  I'd suggest creating a table with a significant amount of data and testing the queries to get an answer.

Comment: Which is why I added the disclaimer about the indexes and table size. If there are only a few rows in each table and no indexes MySQL will recognize that it has to do a full tablcan on both tables and will first join.